# Using and parsing through lists in luigi pipelines

Tags: python, luigi

I am trying to create a luigi pipeline in the following format:

## Task A

Takes in as input a list of sentences, applies a function to each sentence in the list and returns a modified list of said sentences

## Task B

Takes in as input the output modified list of Task A, but also has a requirement that Task A be ran before this task can run. It will apply a function to each element in the list and return a modified list as an output.

Below is some code that I thought would work but for some reason Task B will unsuccesfully run, and I am not sure why?

```
import luigi

class TaskA(luigi.Task):
    sentence = Luigi.ListParameter()
    def output(self):
        # Return the generated list as output
        return luigi.ListParameter(default=[])

    def run(self):
        # Simulating the generation of a list
        output_list = FunctionA(self.sentence)
        self.output().dump(output_list)

    def FunctionA(self):
         # Code goes here....

class TaskB(luigi.Task):
    sentence = Luigi.ListParameter()
    def requires(self):
        return TaskA()

    def output(self):
        # Return the modified list as output
        return luigi.ListParameter(default=[])

    def run(self):
        # Retrieve the output of TaskA
        input_list_from_taskA = self.input().load()

        # Modify the list further (for example, add 10 to each element)
        modified_list_for_taskB = FunctionB(modified_list_from_taskA)

        # Return the modified list as output
        self.output().dump(modified_list_for_taskB)

    def FunctionB(self):
        # Code goes here...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sentences_to_process = [
        "No conjunctions, but I am in love",
        "The network is good but the food is better",
        "Good customer support network not great"
    ]

    luigi.build([TaskB(sentence=s) for s in sentences_to_process], local_scheduler=True)
```

Ive tried the above code and get a succesfull run on Task A but unsuccesful run on Task B

I also dont want the outputs to be LocalTargets, instead I want them to remain as lists